# I need to debug this JS code, but I cannot

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner at programming and I  cannot debug this JavaScript code. would you please do me a favor and help me with that?
thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Question 7</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function redirect(){ 

var name = prompt("What's your name?");

if ((name == agnetha) || (name == bjorn) || (name == benny) || (name ==anni))
{
    window.location = "https://abbasite.com/";
} 
else 
{
    window.location = "https://www.thebeatles.com/";
}
}

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="redirect();">test script</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put the name like agnetha into `''` or `""` like `(name == "agnetha")`

Comment: try name == "agnetha" and so on. name variable returns the name as string and that string has to be compared. Your comparison is comparing name variable to a variable called "agnetha" which is not declared.

Comment: Debug how? You should always explain specifically what the problem is, and what you were expecting the code to do instead. Then we have a clue what we should be looking for. But as others have said, this looks like a simple problem of missing quote marks around the text of the names.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to store the values you are comparing as a string by wrapping each of them in quotes (`' '`/`" "`), then you should also use triple equality(`===`) in if statements and other comparisons such as switch statements as a double equal sigh tests or similarity and converts both into the same type which can cause nasty glitches

**Here is the fixed code:**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Question 7</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function redirect(){ 

var name = prompt("What's your name?");

if ((name === 'agnetha') || (name === 'bjorn') || (name === 'benny') || (name === 'anni'))
{
    window.location = "https://abbasite.com/";
} 
else 
{
    window.location = "https://www.thebeatles.com/";
}
}

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="redirect();">test script</a> 
</body>
</html>
```